# which is better making crystal report with models or connecting directly to sql server?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, crystal-reports, report

I made the crystal report in mvc with modles the problem is showing messages no null values required or databse log on problems . When connect the report to the server directly it works well but how i will change the server name when deploy taking into consideration the application will have many crystal reports.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct connections are much faster. They also make report design/change much simpler.

To change the server, simply use ODBC as the connection method. Let the ODBC DSN definition take care of pointing to the right server. To change the server for all reports, simply change the ODBC DSN definition.  No need to change anything in the reports.